# Can Raspberry Pi Model B be used as JEE applications web server?

Tags: linux, web-server, mysql

I have learnt how to develop web applications with JEE technologies, working in Eclipse IDE, using Apache TomEE server and MySQL database. Until now, I was using local server instance.

I don't have Raspberry Pi, but it sure looks interesting to be used as a web server. Raspberry Pi Model B, has 700MHz CPU and 512Mb of Ram. So, I was wondering is it possible to use this model of Raspberry Pi, to install software that would run JEE web applications (Apache TomEE)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it can.

Here is a small blog about running JBoss on a Pi:
http://jeeonthepi.blogspot.com/2013/08/setting-up-raspberry-pi-installing.html

Another choice could be Resign, which is focused on small solutions:
http://wiki4.caucho.com/Embedded:_Resin_On_Raspberry_Pi

Comment: Welcome to raspberrypi.stackexchange.com and thanks for the imput. It would be helpful to add more information to the answer to get an understanding without following the links given.

Answer (score 1):

It certainly could work - now a more accurate question would be "does this thing have enough horsepower to run my specific application and/or load"... and the answer to THAT depends a lot on what you're actually doing with this application.  I've run a number of these type apps on the Pi, but nothing I do is particularly heavy on the memory or CPU, so it's not a big deal.

Unrelated to the Pi, but another possibility for this type of application is to get yourself a VPS (virtual private server) from any number of vendors - these systems can be exceptionally cheap (literally a few bucks a month) if you're willing to manage them yourself.

Answer (score 1):

I think the main bottleneck to run Java inside a Raspberry is the RAM. If you subtract OS memory, daemon, video, etc; Might be less than 300MB left to run your application.

If is just a web services, with a light database (or even remote db), for internal purposes, it should work.

I advice to run 32bits on everything (OS, libraries, etc).

Comment: It will have to be 32 bit anyway, RPi uses the armv6h architecture. On my fresh Arch Linux install it uses about 100mb idling

Answer (score -1):

Yes,As Apache is the light weight web server .You can go to this link for installation stpes.
https://alextheedom.wordpress.com/raspberry-pi/installing-java-7-and-tomcat-7/